# Keras is saving the wrong epoch with early stopping

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, early-stopping

I was wondering if anyone else has seen this happen with Keras recently.  In the first screenshot, early stopping is triggered (I set patience to be 2 to demonstrate my point) and the best was epoch 4 with a loss of 0.0898.  However, when I next run model.evaluate, you can see that the actual model that was saved was from epoch 5.  On every run I've tried, it consistently saves the epoch that is one after the best epoch.

[image]

Code:

```
initializer = keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval= -0.2, maxval=0.5)
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=K.elu, input_shape=[3],  kernel_initializer=initializer),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=K.elu,  kernel_initializer=initializer),
    keras.layers.Dense(2,  kernel_initializer=initializer)
  ])
```

```
rms = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.01)
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',optimizer=rms)
```

```
es = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='loss', 
    mode='min', 
    patience = 10, 
    restore_best_weights = True, 
    verbose=0)

historyData = model.fit(xarray_norm,yarray_norm,epochs=5,callbacks=[es])
```

```
training_eval = model.evaluate(xarray_norm,yarray_norm,verbose=1)
print()
print('training loss = ', training_eval)
print()
print('History of Loss:')
print(historyData.history)
```

Also, when early stop is not triggered, there appears to be a ghost extra epoch that is run and then stored but is neither printer nor shows up in the history:

[image]

I've run this code multiple times and what's shown in the screenshots consistently happens.  It's not a big deal if you drive the learning rate down so there aren't a lot of fluctuations between epochs but the early stop doesn't appear to be working the way it should.

Edited: I see that the fit output could be impacted by the average over the different batches. But here is the consistency that shows that the restore best weights is always picking the epoch after the best one - the model.evaluate and model.fit outputs for loss are identical:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuDOn.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th91D.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6y9K.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OyT5.png

Comment: The values shown during `fit` are averages over the epoch (while the model is still training). The result from `evaluate` is from a fixed model saved at the end of the epoch. Thus, there will be differences between the two.